# dynamic parameters in UI-Router1.0

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In the very new release of UI-Router1.0.0-alpha.1 Christopher Thielen [announced](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/releases/tag/1.0.0-alpha.1) dynamic parameters. For my understanding, if a param is configured to be dynamic, when changing it from the controller the URL should change accordingly. I tried several methods and couldn't make this happen. There doesn't seem to be binding between $state.params.myParam and $stateParams.myParam.

Can someone please share a working example, or tell me if it is indeed not working?

Thanks

Comment: updated to alpha.3, there is binding between $state.params.myParam and $stateParams.myParam, but still not with $location and the URL. I'm using HTML5 mode, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to just change the dynamic parameter. The location changes when performing state transition, using `ui-sref` or `$state.go()`.

When transitioning to the current state where the only change is in parameters that are defined as dynamic, the controller is not reloaded.

example:

```
$stateProvider.state({
  name: 'home',
  url: '/home/:dynamicParam',
  template: template, 
  controller: controller,
  params: { 
    dynamicParam: { 
      dynamic: true 
    }
  }
});
```

Change the param using: `ui-sref=".({ dynamicParam: newVal })"` or `$state.go('.', { dynamicParam: newVal })`

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MkGSGfPXVC8b6qYqKKjP?p=preview) made by Chris Thielen that demonstrates this.